# Update column data on list via Powershell

Tags: powershell, custom-list

I've got a list where theres one column that needs to be updated on a monthly basis (figures get changed). The list already has a person column so over-writing the whole list each month isn't what I'm after.

I have see some examples on updating a field based on a value. So in this example [from this site](http://sharepointrelated.com/2012/05/03/addedit-list-items-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/) its possible to update items where a value equals something. Which is good because I had a unique 'key' value in the way of a Customer number which I can match on. So basically what I need to do is export a csv of those 2 columns and run through the list see if it matches and update if it does not. My Powershell skills have been a bit neglected of late so its just something I'm trying to put together.

does anyone have an example of a script that when given a CSV it can match and update the 'money' column? thanks

```
#Get all items in this list and save them to a variable
$items = $list.items

#Go through all items
foreach($item in $items)
{
#If the "Title" column value equals "My first item!" do something with it
if($item["Title"] -eq "My first item!")
{
#Change the value of the "Title" column
$item["Title"] = "My first edited item!"

#Update the item
$item.Update()
}
}
```

Comment: What is the help you are looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849891.aspx) to import the CSV data into PowerShell, and then you can loop through it.

So if you have a specific value you want to compare against and then update a list item in SharePoint, in your case comparing `Money` and then updating the list item matching the `Customer number`, the following can be an inspiration:

```
# Load in the CSV
$delimeter = ";"
$filePath = "path to the CSV file"
$csvData = Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter $delimeter

# SharePoint column names
$moneyColumn = "Money"
$customerNoColumn = "CustomerNo"

# Get SharePoint list
$web = Get-SPWeb "site url"
$list = $web.Lists["list name"]

# Loop through each line in the CSV file
foreach ($line in $csvData)
{
    # Get item matching $customerNo
    $customerItem = $list.Items | Where $_.$customerNoColumn -eq $line.$customerNoColumn

    if ($customerItem -ne $null)
    {
        if ($customerItem[$moneyColumn] -ne $line.$moneyColumn)
        {
            $customerItem[$moneyColumn] = $line.$moneyColumn
            $customerItem.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks Daniel. I ended up having to do a nested loop but works as I need. Basically these figures are going to change each month so I've just opted to update the whole list each month.

Answer (score 1):

As per what Daniel suggested;

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

#Load in the CSV
$delimeter = ","
$csvData = Import-Csv C:\CustomerData\customerspend.csv -Delimiter $delimeter

#Site Collection where you want to upload files
$webURL = "http://portal/site/ccp"
#List to update
$listName = "Customer List"

#SharePoint column names
$moneyColumn = "Spend"
$customerNoColumn = "Customer Number"

#Get the SharePoint List
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
#contains the Customer List variable
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

$items = $list.Items


foreach ($line in $csvData)
{ 
    foreach($item in $items)
    {        
        if($item[$customerNoColumn] -eq $line.'Customer Number')
        {
           $item[$moneyColumn] = $line.Spend
            $item.Update();        
        }
     }
}
```